# shiny renderPlot with dynamic height

Tags: css, r, shiny, fluid-layout

**Problem**
I want to change the height of a rendered plot dynamically, so that if it contains a lot of data points more space is allocated to the plot. Content below the plot should then simply be moved.

The  `height` argument of `renderPlot` can be used for that, but then the plot overflows into the next element and I want to avoid that.

I can circumvent that by using `uiOutput`, but I was wondering whether I can get the same behaviour **without**  falling back on `renderUI`?

**Expected Outcome**

I would like the `div` below my plot to be moved when the plot sizes changes, **without** using `renderUI`

**Screenshots**

*Div does not move*
[image: Too small]

*Overflow into div*
[image: Overflow!!]
**Code**

```r
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- fluidPage(
   fluidRow(
      column(width = 2, sliderInput("n", "Number of Rows:", 1, 49, 10)),
      column(width = 10, plotOutput("plot"))
   ),
   fluidRow( ## the plot oevrflows into this div when the plot grows
      column(width = 12, div(style = "background:red; height: 100px"))
   ),
   fluidRow(
    column(width = 10, offset = 2, uiOutput("ui"))
   ),
   fluidRow( ## this div is properly moved down as the plot grows
      column(width = 12, div(style = "background:red; height: 100px"))
   )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   data <- reactive(data.frame(id = factor(1:input$n, 1:input$n), 
                               y  = rpois(input$n, 200)))
   output$plot <- renderPlot(
     qplot(id, y, geom = "col", fill = y, data = data()) + 
        coord_flip(), height = function() 20 * NROW(data())
   )

   output$ui <- renderUI(plotOutput("plot2", height = 20 * NROW(data())))

   output$plot2 <- renderPlot(
     qplot(id, y, geom = "col", fill = y, data = data()) + 
        coord_flip()
   )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write `plotOutput("plot", height = "auto")` in the ui part. The default height of plotOutput are fixed 400 pixels. By setting height="auto" the plot automatically adjusts to the content.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but from the help file from `plotOutput`:  *Note that, for height, using ‘"auto"’ or ‘"100%"’ generally will not work as expected, because of how height is computed with HTML/CSS.*

Comment: Ok, I did not know that. Still, it works fine in your example. Increasing the number of rows to 1000 and more does not seem to make a problem.

Comment: Hmm, with `height="auto"` I get the following warning `Warning: Error in pngfun: invalid 'width' or 'height'` and the plot is barely visible at all...

Comment: I get the same error message when I delete `height = function() 20 * NROW(data()` in the the server part. Apparently you need both the appropriate height in the server's renderPlot and height = "auto" in the ui's plotOutput.

Comment: Excellent, that's what I was looking for!